# Getting C++ As Parameter Value, Result Only C By Using Php

Tags: php, url-parameters, url-parsing

test.php?aa=c++ and echo $_GET['aa'] result only c without ++

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['aa'];
 ?>
```

Comment: Err... what is your question?

Comment: Try calling `test.php?aa=c%2B%2B`. `+` is encoded as `%2B`. You may need to call [urldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) on `$_GET['aa']`.

Comment: OP visits url.com/test.php?aa=c++ and wants to print `c++` (i.e. what's behind `aa=`) but it only prints `c`.

Comment: Don't post ALLCAPS, it's considered shouting/rude.

Comment: Learn about URL-encoding.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the symbol for `+` is treated as white space by your browser or HTTP client! If you want to actually send the symbol `+` in your get request, please encode it first in your web browser.

You can try converting your `C++` with tools such as this one https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP.